# 2D physic engine for VB?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, dll, 2d, physics-engine

I would like to use a physic engine to make a 2D motorbike game in Visual Studio 2010, in a Windows Form (VB language).

It looks like I can import some C# DLLs of physic engines, but I don't find any that are already exported in DLL and that are ready and simple to use. I want to do this for school and push the subject further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this one : http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=8679&lngWId=10

But it is really basic and there is no documentation. I think I will build my own from what I remember from my physics classes and with Internet's support.